# Redis get function returning connection error

Tags: python, python-2.7, redis

```
import redis
if redis_client.get(news_digest) is None:
            num_of_news += 1
            news['digest'] = news_digest
```

Hey guys, I'm following an online course and I'm not familiar with Redis at all, so I literally have no idea what's going on. Seems like it raises a Connection Error, but I don't know how to fix it. Thank you guys so much.

```
if redis_client.get(news_digest) is None:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1332, in get
    return self.execute_command('GET', name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 836, in execute_command
    conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1073, in get_connection
    connection.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 544, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 61 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.
```

Comment: You need to connect first... `r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)`

Comment: Do you have Redis running on the localhost at port 6379? If not, you should...

Comment: @MarkSetchell it has a line of code to connect. "redis_client = redis.StrictRedis(REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT)"

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks! I solved it by installing redis by using brew....